# Why closure makes type guard be ignored in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In this example, after making sure `key` has value, it's reused in a closure, but typescript still thinks it can be `null`, yet it doesn't complain about `key2`.

```
let data: {[k: string]: string} = {}
function deleteOnClick() {
    let key = findKey()
    if (!key) {
        return;
    }
    let key2 = key
    window.addEventListener("click", () => {
        delete data[key2] // this is ok
        delete data[key] // type error, key can be null
    })
}

function findKey(): string | null {
    return null
}
```

How can I make typescript accept `key` without declaring a variable unnecessarily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `let key` to `const key`. With that TypeScript knows that the referenced value will be the same when the closure is executed.